# CanExecute works only partial

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, relaycommand, mvvm-toolkit

I am working on a WPF .NET 5 application that needs to handle a longer task using a button command. Until the task is done, the button should be disabled.
I am using the RelayCommand from Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm:
`BtnCmd = new RelayCommand(DoSomething, CanDoSomething);`
The first thing the DoSomething method does is make the return value of `CanDoSomething` false. This prevents DoSomething from being executed again, but it is not visually visible on the Button.
While researching, I came across that this is indeed the case on https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/issues/41:

> *"Sergio0694 commented on Mar 28, 2021"*: "That is correct, by default RelayCommand will not automatically update its visual state on WPF...".

The solution he recommends is using: https://gist.github.com/Sergio0694/130bc344e552e501563546454bd4e62a and

```xml
<button xmlns:input="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.Wpf.Input"    
        Command="{Binding Command}"
        input:RelayCommandExtensions.IsCommandUpdateEnabled="True"/>
```

My DoSomething Mehod looks like this:

```
private async void DoSomething()
{
    PropertyCheckedByCanDoSomething = false;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    PropertyCheckedByCanDoSomething = true;
}
```

It will give the desired visual effect, but only on the line: `PropertyCheckedByCanDoSomething = false;`
With `PropertyCheckedByCanDoSomething = true;` the effect is only visible after clicking into the application or doing a window switch.
How can I fix this?
Thanks a lot for any support.

Comment: Is `PropertyCheckedByCanDoSomething` firing a PropertyChanged event?

Comment: If you like to use a different MVVM framework have a look at https://reactiveui.net

Comment: @Neil Yes as documented:`set => SetProperty(ref _propertyCheckedByCanDoSomething, value);}`

Comment: The DoSomething call is not awaited. Anything happing after `await Task.Delay` will not affect the UI. Except the UI is somehow also bound to PropertyCheckedByCanDoSomething , we do not know. You may search the web for an AsyncRelayCommand implementation.

Comment: @Clemens I changed the code to AsyncRelayCommand. Does not help. BTW: Everything works as expected except the visual representation of the button. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how all your bindings and such are going, with I might approach it by subclassing your relay command, something like

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace MyTestApp
{
    public class MyRelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public MyRelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, CanAlwaysExecute)
        { }

        public MyRelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            // Lamda expression to execute each respectively
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object cmdParm)
        { return _canExecute(cmdParm); }

        public static bool CanAlwaysExecute(object cmdParm)
        {   return true;    }

        public void Execute(object cmdParm)
        {
            if (!_doingWithCallback)
                _execute(cmdParm);
            else
                Execute2(cmdParm);
        }

        // The CanExecuteChanged event handler is required from the ICommand interface
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        private bool _isMyTaskRunning = false;
        public bool IsMyTaskRunning
        { get { return _isMyTaskRunning; } }

        private bool _doingWithCallback;
        private readonly Action<object, Action> _executeWithCallback;

        public MyRelayCommand(Action<object, Action> executeWithCallback) : this( executeWithCallback, CanAlwaysExecute)
        { }

        public MyRelayCommand(Action<object, Action> executeWithCallback, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            // new flag, so when the default "Execute" method is called, it can then redirect to
            // calling the Execute2() method that checks to prevent the double-click and then
            // calls your function with the additional parameter of the action method to call upon completion.
            _doingWithCallback = true;
            _executeWithCallback = executeWithCallback;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public void Execute2(object cmdParm)
        {
            // prevent double action if running vs not
            if (_isMyTaskRunning)
                return;

            // flag it to prevent double action
            _isMyTaskRunning = true;

            // trigger raising the CanExecute changed which will update the user interface
            RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

            // turn off when done, but if being done from a "task()" process, 
            // you probably want to have a return function be called when the 
            // TASK is finished to re-enable the button... maybe like

            // NOW, call your execute function that accepts TWO parameters.
            // the first is whatever parameter MAY come from the button click itself.
            // the SECOND parameter will be to accept MY ACTION HERE to reset the flag when finished
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => _executeWithCallback(cmdParm, ButtonTaskIsComplete));
        }

        public void ButtonTaskIsComplete()
        {
            _isMyTaskRunning = false;
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); });
        }
    }
}
```

May not be a perfect fit, but might offer a possible wrapper solution for you.

And here is a sample implementation to call it in your existing form area.

```
private MyRelayCommand _myFormButton;
public MyRelayCommand MyFormButton
{ get { return _myFormButton ?? ( _myFormButton = new MyRelayCommand( YourFormMethod )); } }

public void YourFormMethod(object cmdParm, System.Action doThisWhenFinished)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something from after the click event of the button");

    // NOW, the callback function so the button re-enables itself once finished.
    doThisWhenFinished();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this code. It may leed me to the right way. There are however some obstacles.  ` CanExecute` initially disables my Button because initially _isMyTaskRunning is false. In addition I wonder that such a ordinary topic leads to efforts like this.

Comment: @ebiondi, oops... changed to NOT in the canExecute call ( !_isMyTaskRunning ).  As for efforts like this... not always, but its sometimes hard to encapsulate and it was mostly a snippet of existing code I just tacked on the extra _isMyTaskRunning portion.

Comment: Thank you again! Now I can push the button but I get a `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'` in `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`. Any ideas?

Comment: @ebiondi, it is probably due to the separate task thread not being the same as the UI thread.  So, see revision in the ButtonTaskIsComplete() method using the dispatcher to invoke the refresh.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. In the meantime, I have uploaded the code https://github.com/gitiondi/CanExecute. But now the execute method is not called anymore:-( The current (2nd) commit uses MyRelayCommand.

Comment: @ebiondi, did not change the Execute event, just the result of the ContinueWith component.  Should not have had an impact for the initial calling.

Comment: Yes I agree in theory. But when I comment the ContinueWith part it works again.

Comment: @ebiondi, see revision for creating an execute method that allows for extra ACTION parameter to act as a callback before IT finishes, thus resetting the flag/refresh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241675/discussion-between-ebiondi-and-drapp).

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with that [RelayCommandExtension](https://gist.github.com/Sergio0694/130bc344e552e501563546454bd4e62a) you refered to.

There exists a [Github issue](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/issues/41) regarding this. The following [solution](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/issues/41#issuecomment-979745843) was posted there:

In `RelayCommandExtensions.cs` add the following line:

```
notifiers.Add(obj, notifier);
```

to the  `OnIsCommandUpdateEnabledChanged(...)` method so that it looks like that:

```
// Ensure a notifier is enabled so that we can monitor for changes to the command
// property in the future. This is also needed in case this attached property is
// set before the binding engine has actually resolved the target command instance.
if (!notifiers.TryGetValue(obj, out _))
{
    PropertyChangeNotifier notifier = new(obj, nameof(ICommandSource.Command));

    notifier.PropertyChanged += (_, _) => ToggleIsCommandUpdateEnabled(obj);
    
    notifiers.Add(obj, notifier);
}
```

This is doing the trick for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution looks really simple. I even looked at the Github issue. But probably not so detailed:-) Thanks for the contribution.